# jQuery - Round Up all Currency Prices with Multiple Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working in Shopify with it's currency switcher and the problem is, the client I'm working with wants every currency bar the default (GBP) to round it's price up to the nearest whole number, so $458.54 becomes $459.

I almost got it to work, except when more than one `.money` element is present, it seems to break and merges them together.

The JS code is:

```
var all = $(".money")
 .map(function() {
return this.innerHTML;
})
.get();

var all = [all, ","];
var arrayLength = all.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  //Do something
}
console.log("array:", all);
var regex = all.toString().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");

var regex = [regex, ","];
var regexarrayLength = regex.length;
for (var i = 0; i < regexarrayLength; i++) {
 //Do something
}
console.log("arrayregex:", regex);
console.log("regex:", regex);
var rounded_currency = Math.round(regex);
console.log("rounded_currency:", rounded_currency);
$("#update").click(function() {
   alert(rounded_currency);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".priceUpdate").text(regex);
   $(".priceRound").text(rounded_currency);
});
```

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/ConduciveMammal/pen/bWrPwX?editors=0001)

Comment: To round the price use ´Math.round(6453.65)´, but don't forget to remove commas, otherwise it wil read the comma and round to 6, instead of 6454 (number from your CodePen example)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

Changing array of prices to rounded prices array,as regex is not a proper array that is why it is throwing NaN

Updated codepen with JPY value for testing

```
 console.log("array:", all);

    var prices = all[0].map(function(num){
      return var prices = all[0].map(function(num){
  return Math.round(num.replace(/,/g, '').substr(1));
})
console.log(prices)
    })
    console.log(prices);//rounded prices [6454,6454,454,644,6564454]
```

Codepen-https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/VbMZBz?editors=1111

Comment: Hmm actually, this is producing NaN on any currency except for JPY

Comment: JPY? didnt get you?

Comment: Sorry, Japanese Yen.
On USD, CAD, GBP it produces Nan
And on JPY it produces 72577257 when the price is ¥7,257

Comment: could you please update code with JPY just for testing?

Comment: I'm sorry, for some reason, on CodePen, it works perfectly, it's just on a live site that it doesn't. Perhaps it's the way the JS currencies are loading

Comment: Updated check it once

Comment: updated Current codepen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/VbMZBz?editors=1111 with JPY for testing..check it once

Comment: Hmmm I'm not certain that worked as expected? It actually kept the decimal digits but removed the currency symbol ha!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of javascript's [Math.ceil()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) function to round up to the nearest integer.

For example, loop over the array of all selectors with the `.money` class and first strip the dollar sign. Then call Math.ceil().

```
var all = $(".money").map(function() {
    return this.innerHTML;
}).get();
//["$6453.65", "$6453.65", "$453.65", "$643.65", "$6564453.65"]

var rounded = all.map(function(x) {
  var numbers = x.replace(/[^0-9]/, '');
  return Math.ceil(numbers);
});
//[6454, 6454, 454, 644, 6564454]
```